# How to interrogate/alter a database sequence in python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm using alembic and sqlalchemy to work with different database types. I use an own create_sequence-methode and the drop_sequence-method of Operations from alembic.
Now I'm making unittests to test my functionality. I want to alter/interrogate the sequence that I created before. But how?

```
    def create_sequence(self, sequence):
        kwargs_list = sequence
        self.oprt.execute(CreateSequence(sequence))

    def drop_sequence(self, sequence_name):
        self.oprt.drop_sequence(sequence_name)
```

self.oprt is initialized like this:

```
 engine = create_engine(connection_string, echo=True)  # echo=True to get executed sql
 conn = engine.connect()
 ctx = MigrationContext.configure(connection=conn)
 self.oprt = Operations(ctx)
```

I tried already to get a Sequence object with the help of the engine-object or an Metadata-Object. It doesn't work yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some ideas I tested with with postgresql so I'm not sure how many other dbs support these.

#### Get `next_value()` of sequence.

```py
engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=True)

Base = declarative_base()

metadata = Base.metadata

seq_name = 'counter'

from sqlalchemy import Sequence

counter_seq = Sequence(seq_name, metadata=metadata)

metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    res = session.execute(select(counter_seq.next_value())).scalar()
    assert res > 0
```

#### Use `inspect` and check if sequence name is listed

```py
from sqlalchemy import inspect
ins = inspect(engine)
assert seq_name in ins.get_sequence_names()
```

#### postgresql only -- check `currval` manually

I know there is a way to check the current sequence value in postgresql but it doesn't seem that sqlalchemy support that directly.  You could do it manually like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import func, select

with Session(engine) as session:
    res = session.execute(select(func.currval(seq_name))).scalar()
    assert res > 0
```

Comment: I'm using no sessions and use the execute from engine (but minor matter). The next_value() variant works and the inspect variant too. I need to test it with currval(), but I use oracle too. So it's not necessary. Thank you!